# Is it bad to not disconnect a MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad to not disconnect a MutationObserver?

I'm performing an observation for new elementes added to the DOM, but I'm never performing an explicit disconnection. Could this cause memory issues?

Comment: You mean, you need your MutationObserver to do stuff for the entire duration of the website being viewed?

Comment: @Siguza at least while certain jQuery is open using this feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need your MutationObserver only once (e.g. for initialization or whatever), you should disconnect it after it's no longer used. This might or might not free some memory, but it will certainly decrease CPU load.

If your MutationObserver is required for the normal functioning of your website and would only have to be disconnected when the user closes their tab or window, I would say disconnecting is not required, as the browser has to clean up anyway. I mean, you *could* unregister event handlers as well, but no-one really does that. And certainly no-one deletes all their functions and variables, they expect the browser to do that.
It might even be faster to **not** disconnect your MutationObserver, as the cleanup code is (almost certainly) written in machine code, which executes much faster than JavaScript. The difference would most likely be unnoticeable though.

And since you specifically ask

> Could this cause memory issues?

Yes, it **could** create a memory leak. But so could declaring a variable, if the browser does not perform appropriate cleanup, which would be a bug in that browser.
Assuming a sane environment though, you should be fine without disconnecting your MO.

Comment: What if a parent node of a node you're observing is removed from the document? You can still reference the node if code has reference to it, but are MutationObservers unregistered?

Comment: @NoBugs As long as you have a reference, you can still add it to the DOM again, so any observer *shouldn't* be disconnected. I created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL81b6w5/3/) to test this, and Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera all don't disconnect. However, if you have *no* reference to the node and the observer anymore, the garbage collector should eventually kick in and silently phase both out of existence (except for IE maybe, because IE is broken). You could probably test this by adding a bazillion observers to a node, removing it from the DOM and watch the browser's memory usage.